How can I back up Debian 12, if it is with logical volumes are placed in different drives?
I know how to:

make snapshot of LV (logical volume)
back up the system by dd.

So, I'd like to know how to back up the system which resides in logical volumes of only one volume group? And I have two drives (if it's matter).

Would you mind clarifying your issue? Is your problem that your system uses multiple LVs?

@Kusalananda, yes, I understand how to back up (clone) the system with usual partitions, but don't know how to make the same for the system with LVs.
